# Roccat Swarm monitor.exe freezing i need automatic restart

Tags: process, freeze

is this happening to anyone? Out of nowhere, the Roccat Swarm monitor.exe process freezes most often when I play a game on Steam. I've tried everything I know. Thanks for any advice. I´m also added video : https://youtube.com/shorts/pR6MSnotdYk?feature=share
[here you can see freeze process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c4At.png)

I would need some advice on a script that could restart this process if it freezes like this at 0%. I tried to create a powershell script that would check cpu usage, but powershell always reports that the process was not found. It will be written even if the process is actually running. Thanks for any advice. Have a nice day